# Conditional styling based on whenever there is a certain field value added by cms in React/Typescript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-operator

In my React/Typescript component I render a `<Link />` component whenever the value (`data.link?.text` and `data?.link?.url`) is added by the CMS.

```
{data.link?.text && data?.link?.url && (
 <Link to={data?.link?.url}>
)}
```

I use Typescript [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) to conditionally render the `Link` or not. So if the `text` and `url` of the link field are filled it renders the `<Link />` component.

The Link type:

```
export type Link = {
 link: {
   url: string;
   text: string;
 };
}
```

If the `Link` component doesn't exist on the page/isn't rendered I want to add some styling (`margin-bottom`) to the `List` component.

The structure of the component looks like this:

```
<List>
 <div css={styles.list}>
  // Mapped list items here
 </div>
</List>

{data.link?.text && data?.link?.url && (
 <Link css={styles.link} to={data?.link?.url}>
  {data.link.text}
 </Link>
)}
```

So somehow I have to create a boolean and based on that boolean, in my `MyComponent.styles.ts` I can do something like:

```
margin-bottom: ${haslink ? `0` : `35px`};
```

Comment: Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the parent component to see how it's conditionally rendering the link and surrounding components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could create a div with the extra margin bottom that you can conditionally render based on the link url.

```
<List>
  <div css={styles.list}>
    // Mapped list items here
  </div>
</List>

{data.link?.text && data?.link?.url ? (
  <Link css={styles.link} to={data.link.url}>
    {data.link.text}
  </Link>
) : (
  <div style={{ marginBottom: '35px' }} /> // <-- adjust how you style this element as needed
)}
```